# How can I add authorization header to a get request using node.js WITHOUT external modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Ive attempted this below:

```js
      let options = {
        hostname: `api.genius.com`,
        path: `/${data}?text_format=plain`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${config.GeniusBearerToken}`,
          'Host': `api.genius.com`
        }
      };


      https.get(options, (res) => {
        const { statusCode } = res;
        const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
        let error;
        if (statusCode !== 200) {
          error = new Error('Request Failed. ' + `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
        } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
          error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' + `Expected text/html; charset=UTF-8 but received ${contentType}`);
        }
        if (error) {
          res.end(`<html> ERROR: ${e.message} </html>`)
          console.error(error.message);
          // Consume response data to free up memory
          res.resume();
          return;
        }
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
          try {
            console.log(rawData)
          } catch (e) {
            res.end(`<html> ERROR: ${e.message} </html>`)
            console.error(e.message);
          }
      }).on('error', (e) => {
        res.end(`<html> ERROR: ${e.message} </html>`)
        console.error(`Error: ${e.message}`);
      });
    });
```

As shown in my example everything works perfectly except im getting a 401 unauthorized code with the api, my config IS defined correctly and the config value is correct alongside with the header syntax, i just believe im doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your token isn't expired?

Comment: Im quite positive, I just checked.

Comment: Try setup a local node dummy server, and see if the request is submited as needed.
If everything works and header/body looks like excepted, it can only be a invalid token.